# Evaluating Tensorflow Tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

to get the gradients of the output with respect to the input, 
one can use

```
grads = tf.gradients(model.output, model.input)
```

where grads =

```
[<tf.Tensor 'gradients_81/dense/MatMul_grad/MatMul:0' shape=(?, 18) dtype=float32>]
```

This is a modell, where there are 18 continous inputs and 1 continous output.

I assume, this is a symbolic expression and that one needs a list of 18 entries to feed it to the tensor, such that it gives out the derivatives as floats.

I would use

```
Test =[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    alpha = sess.run(grads, feed_dict = {model.input : Test})
    print(alpha)
```

But I get the error

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Error while reading resource variable dense_2/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense_2/bias)
     [[Node: dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp = ReadVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](dense_2/bias)]]
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:
This is, what has happened before:

```
def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([ 
            ...])
    optimizer = ...
    model.compile(loss='mse'... ) 
    return model 


model = build_model()
history= model.fit(data_train,train_labels,...)
loss, mae, mse = model.evaluate(data_eval,...)
```

---

Progress so far:

```
Test =[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
    tf.initializers.variables(model.output)
    alpha = sess.run(grads, feed_dict = {model.input : Test})
```

is also not working, giving the error:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Comment: What happens if you run `out = sess.run(model.output, feed_dict = {model.input : Test})`? I am guessing this error does not have to do with the gradients in particular, but the model itself is somehow missing.

Comment: If you let it run in "with tf.Session() as sess:" you will get    "FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Error while reading resource variable dense_26/bias from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense_26/bias)
  [[Node: dense_26/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp = ReadVariableOp[dtype=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](dense_26/bias)]]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use uninitialized variable. All you have to do is add

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

right after `with tf.Session() as sess:`

Edit:
You need to register session with Keras

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

And use `tf.initializers.variables(var_list)` instead of `tf.global_variables_initializer()`

See https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html

Edit:

```
Test = np.ones((1, 18), dtype=np.float32)

inputs = layers.Input(shape=[18,])
layer = layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
checkpointer = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='path/weights.hdf5')
model.fit(Test, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=1, callbacks=[checkpointer])
grads = tf.gradients(model.output, model.input)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    model.load_weights('path/weights.hdf5')
    alpha = sess.run(grads, feed_dict={model.input: Test})
    print(alpha)
```

This shows consistent result

Comment: Hello, this is not working. If you apply it several times, it will always give different results for the same input. I have the feeling, that it initializes all the weights. But the weights should be fixed, since they have been trained before.

Comment: I think it's a different problem. If you try this on a synthetic constant data it will show the same result. How do you load model.output?

Comment: I use , model = build_model() and then model.fit() and model.evaluate(). The model itself is a Keras Sequential model.  I wrote it into the question.

Comment: This should be ok for your case

Comment: Thank you. Should I use it in "with tf.Session() as sess"? And which variables should I put into var_list if I don't want to overwrite the weights trained in the model?

Comment: It is working, if you use https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models for saving the weights.